# updatable entities in the design of databases

Tags: database-design

I have a question on Entity Relationship design.

It is a shop where products are kept in stock first and then go to the store. When the store has less than a certain amount of product, products that are in stock go to the store. How would you design these entities?

I thought two entities `products_store` and `products_stock` but I don't know if there is another, more practical way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have two entities `products_store` and `products_stock` as depicted in your question.

Other Options

> Incase you just need a track of which product is moved

I think of having single `Products` table with a column name it as `In_stock` (can be a `bit` field) where you change it to false, when the product is moved to store.

`In_stock` value options

`1`- InStock

`0`- InStore

> Incase you need a track of DateTime when the product is moved to store.

I think of having single `Products` table with one column called `Move_DateTime` (default value `NULL`) to update the column when the product is moved to store from stock.

`Move_DateTime` value options

`NULL` - InStock

`DateTimevalue` -InStore

In one possible scenario you can go for choosing both the columns to be added in the table.